# Page Redirection in Micro Slim PHP Framework?

Tags: php, slim

i am facing issue regarding Page Redirection in **PHP Micro Slim Framework @version 2.3.5**.
i have already Try few Ways to Redirect but all the way i try are not working.

Actually i have a login Page and on submit i am calling the The Login Check Function which i have write and it is working properly. But finally after Successful MATCH of Username and Password, i want to redirect on another page.

the ways i have already tried are below:

```
return $response->withRedirect('/dashboard.php');   

return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', 'http://localhost/kafcashapp/dashboard.php');

$app->redirect('http://localhost/kafcashapp/dashboard.php', 301); 

header("Location: http://localhost/kafcashapp/dashboard.php");
```

Below are the Code to Check Login

```
$app->post('/login', function() use ($app) {
            // check for required params
            verifyRequiredParams(array('email', 'password'));

            // reading post params
            $email = $app->request()->post('email');
            $password = $app->request()->post('password');
            $response = array();

            $db = new DbHandler();
            // check for correct email and password
            if ($db->checkLogin($email, $password)) {
                // get the user by email
                $user = $db->getUserByEmail($email);

                if ($user != NULL) {
                    $response["error"] = false;
                    $response['name'] = $user['name'];
                    $response['email'] = $user['email'];
                    $response['apiKey'] = $user['api_key'];
                    $response['createdAt'] = $user['created_at'];  

                } else {
                    // unknown error occurred
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = "An error occurred. Please try again";
                }
            } else {
                // user credentials are wrong
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = 'Login failed. Incorrect credentials';
            }

            //echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });
```

any Suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/helpers/#redirect) you can do `302 Temporary Redirect` with the following.

```
$app->redirect("/bar");
```

If you need `301 Moved Permanently` instead you need to specify the status code manually.

```
$app->redirect("/bar", 301);
```

Comment: *@Mika Tuupola* Thanks for reply but i have tried already. it is not working.

Comment: First step would be to upgrade Slim to 2.6